# Django dynamic model choice modifiable in the web applicaton

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Suppose I have a model with choice, see below (this is the django doc example).
What I need is that my web application be able to dynamically add and delete choices and I need my model to get updated with those choices. In fact, the best way would be to have choices stored in a separate database and the model to have a relationship to them via ForeignKey. How do I modify the code so that I will still have selectable choices in the model? Thanks.

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):

    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        ('FR', 'Freshman'),
        ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
        ('JR', 'Junior'),
        ('SR', 'Senior'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                  choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                  default=FRESHMAN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Tuple` is an Immutable object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm), and you would *not* be able to add/remove choices. To achieve what you are looking for, you need a persistent storage. In other words, it as to be stored/retrieved from the database.

What I would recommend is, making this a `ForeignKey` field, and load the existing choices as an [initial fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures) into the database.

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    year_in_school = models.ForeignKey('YearChoices', default= get_default_year())

class YearChoices(models.Model):
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

One way I can think of implementing it would be, in the form, have a [`CharField` with autocomplete choices](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoCompleteSolutions#DjangoJavaScriptAuto-CompleteSolutions) from `YearChoices` table , and on `POST`, if the choice does *not* exist, create a new entry in the `YearChoices` table.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the user would only edit the choices indirectly through a different view, so I do not really need the "autocomplete" feature. The question is: how to render these ForeignKeys in the form. Let's say I have a ModelForm that creates form from the above Student model. How do I specify the ForeignKey choices with a widget in that ModelForm?

Comment: it is quite straight forward. ForeignKeys by default renders a choices widget.